# Rails: Relate two records after creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have his model in Rails:

```
class Commission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :commissions
end
```

This model generates three tables: commission, book and books_commissions.
In the first process of my app generate and save commissions and books without relating entries.

**Question**: How create a record in books_commissions if I know the book_id and commission_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have an object `book` from the model Book and an object `commission` from the model Commission.

Then `book.commissions << commission` should do the trick.